# flume spoolDir+kafka channel got encoding error

Tags: apache-kafka, flume

i was using flume spool DIR source and KAFKA channel, but i found a strange thing when i try to read data from KAFKA : a random char is added in the front of some of the string lines.

`\10:22:40    53311312321     是的线程否否  ..... 
 s15:22:30    15233223213     飒飒汝非 ....
 13:22:30    15233223213      飒飒事情非 ....`

the encoding is U T F-8.
i think the issue is about the Chinese character , which uses 4 bit to write one.
anyone know about this?

Answer (score -1):

We were experiencing this same condition using an exec source and kafka channel.

The condition appeared to be corrected when we set

```
parseAsFlumeEvent = true
```

in the channel configuration.

[Kafka_flume](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-kafka/latest/topics/kafka_flume.html)